# Conventions for making Stanford Ner CRF Training data

Tags: stanford-nlp, crf, crf++

I have to make a good NER CRF based model. I am targeting a vast domain and total no of classes that I am targeting are 17. I have also made a good set of features set(austen.prop) that should work for me by doing a lot of experiments. NER is not producing good results. I need to know **limitations of NER** which is CRF based in context of training data size etc.

I searched a lot but till now I am unable to find the conventions that one should follow in making training data.

(Note: I know completely how to make model and use it, I just need to know is there any conventions that some percentage of each target class should exist etc.)

If anybody can guide me, I would be thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

For English, a standard training data set is CoNLL 2003 which has something like 15,000 tagged sentences for 4 classes (ORG, PERSON, LOCATION, MISC).

Comment: It is really helpful. Can you also guide me about limitations of NER?